# MDI child form is not allowing other child forms to get focus

Tags: focus, mdichild

The application is an MDI container app. A specific child form (Form1) when loaded gets focus and will not release the focus. If another form is opened up, the user is not able to select any field within that form if the Form1 form is open.

Also, within the Form1, the focus will not leave a combobox even to set focus to another field on the same form.

I am not using ShowDialog and TopMost is set to false.

Comment: I am amusing this is in c# based on your question history, but you may want to state that somewhere.

Comment: I added it to the tags, because I was scolded for putting the language in the title. But when the question was saved it didn't keep the C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have any methods assigned to the Leave event for the combobox, it sounds as though your application is setting the combobox to the active control whenever it loses focus.

Your form may also have the same type of code implemented, setting it to the active form when it loses focus.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it actually led me to find the solution. The combo box was not allowing nulls to be entered, so when it got focus it would not leave until something was selected.